# New command: Hypothesis

Tags: amsmath

I'm new with Latex and trying to get four hypotheses in the following style:

> **Hypothesis 1 (H1):** *This is my first hypothesis.*

I'm using the `amsmath` package and the following code:

```
\newcommand{hyp}{Hypothesis} 

\begin{hyp}

This is my first hypothesis.

\end{hyp}
```

which gives an output of:

> **Hypothesis 1:** This is my first hypothesis.

I do know how to enumerate the 4 hypotheses but I do not know how to get the H1 to H4 in the brackets.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.StackExchange!  I would like to help you, but I doubt this is the exact code you’re using, I see at least two problems with it (`\newcommand` should be followed by a command name starting with a backslash, and in this case you would define a command, not an environment).  Please post the exact content of the file that is causing problem.

Comment: @Tasia maybe with `enumerate` package ...

Answer (score 12):

You could use the [ntheorem](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ntheorem/) package to get the desired formatting of the `hyp` environment. (Be sure to compile the example code below *twice*, so that LaTeX can resolve the embedded cross-reference.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothesis}

\begin{document}

\begin{hyp}[H\ref{hyp:first}] \label{hyp:first}
This is my first hypothesis.
\end{hyp}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore. ("Something's wrong, perhaps a missing \item")

Comment: @reggie - The code above does *not* cause an error when compiled with MacTeX2022, LaTeX2e `<2021-11-15> patch level 1`, and ntheorem `Version 1.33 <2011/08/15>`. Please tell me more about your document setup. For sure, the type of error message would appear to indicate that you're using a list-like environment, which isn't the case in the code I provided.