# Hypothesis with amsthm package

Tags: amsthm

[image]I'm trying to write a null hypothesis with my thesis, and I found this question [Hypothesis in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247036/new-command-hypothesis). But when I tried it, it did not work for me, as I had a typesetting error and the `xcolor` and `fancyhdr` page were the culprits. (I dont even understand how that is possible, but then again I'm super new at this, so maybe that's not surprising).

Anyway, I've read that I can use the amsthm package to write the hypothesis, but I haven't been able to find a working example.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothesis}
\begin{document}
\begin{hyp}
This is my first hypothesis.
\end{hyp}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean with “null hypothesis”?

Comment: I want it to be H_0 and H_1.

Comment: Can you please add an approximate representation of the desired output?

Comment: I need something like that, to declare my hypothesis. I know I can do it by \textbf{$H_0$}: This is my hypothesis. 
But I need to keep track of them, and it also feels like cheating

Answer (score 5):

Is it what you want?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=6pt, spacebelow=6pt,
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=0.6em,
headpunct=:
]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle, name=Hypothesis, preheadhook={\renewcommand{\thehyp}{H\textsubscript{\arabic{hyp}}}}]{hyp}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{hyp}{hypothesis}{hypotheses}
\Crefname{hyp}{Hypothesis}{Hypotheses}

 \begin{document}
 \setcounter{hyp}{-1}
 \begin{hyp}[Test hypothesis] \label{hyp:a}This is my first hypothesis. \end{hyp}
 \begin{hyp} \label{hyp:b}This is my second hypothesis. \end{hyp}

  \Cref{hyp:a,hyp:b}.

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is amazing, but it does not work for me. It says Package thmtools warning: Your backend doesn't allow theorems on input line 18. Package thmtools error, \declaretheorem key 'spaceabove' not known

Comment: It worked! I moved the amsmath package line up, and loading it before this. Thank you! It's exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Ar1229 Please accept the answer.